# Spring Boot and Logback by Example

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, logback, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot app that (basically) has the following project structure:

```
myapp/
    src/
        <All Java source code here>
    build.gradle
    application.yml
    logback.groovy
```

And its `build.gradle` dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
        ,'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
        ,'ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:1.1.7'
    )
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
}
```

The `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: 'DEBUG'
server:
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
spring:
  datasource:
    test-on-borrow: true
    validation-query: SELECT 1
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
```

And the `logback.groovy`:

```
statusListener(OnConsoleStatusListener)

appender('CONSOLE', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
    }
}

appender('ROLLING', RollingFileAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        Pattern = '%d %level %thread %mdc %logger - %m%n'
    }
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
        FileNamePattern = '/Users/myuser/logs/myapp/myapp-%d{yyyy-MM}.zip'
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew bootRun -Pspring.config=.` (where `spring.config=.` implies the `myapp/application.yml` config file), I see console output only. Nothing gets logged to `/Users/myuser/logs/myapp/`. Any ideas as to why?

---

#### Update

I have created a barebones Spring Boot app that uses my identical Logback config:

https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/spring-boot-logback-example

Clone it and run it by running:

```
./gradlew bootRun -Pspring.config=.
```

Note that even though the app starts up fine (and you will see lots of *console* output), that it does not in fact create a `/var/log/spring-boot-logback-example/spring-boot-logback-example.log` file as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to following to logback.groovy

```
root(DEBUG, ["CONSOLE", "ROLLING"])
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom Van Rossom (+1) - but after trying your suggestion, I'm still not seeing any log files under `/Users/myuser/logs/myapp/`when the app runs.

Comment: Groovy is not on the classpath? Add "compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4''  to build.gradle. "logback.groovy" won't be picked up by default.

Comment: Hi @Tom Van Rossom (+1 again) - But I do in fact have Groovy on the classpath.  I figured it would be easier for you to see a complete working code example. Take a look at my update. If you can, clone that project and run it locally. You'll notice that the log file is not created. Maybe this will clue you in better as to why this isn't working. Thanks again!

Comment: Also @Tom Van Rossom, just a fleeting thought, does the Spring Boot app need to be running in "prod mode" (as a packaged uberjar) in order for its logging system to pick up Logback dependencies/configs? If so, that would explain what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the application successfully after making the following changes to your code:

1. Moved line `root(DEBUG, ["CONSOLE", "ROLLING"])` in `logback.groovy` to the last line, after the appenders are declared
2. I changed the path of the log file from `/var/log` to home directory and the logs started appearing in console and log file. The reason for logs not being generated in `/var/log` directory is lack of permissions

Answer (score 0):

Create a `src/main/resources` folder and place `logback.groovy` in it.

That worked for me with your project (cloned from Github) and the following logback file:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG

appender("FILE", RollingFileAppender) {
  file = "logFile.log"
  rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
    fileNamePattern = "logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
    maxHistory = 30
  }
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n"
  }
}
root(DEBUG, ["FILE"])
```

Answer (score 0):

With logback/spring boot and a groovy config.  The custom log configuration should be in a file named **logback-spring.groovy** instead of **logback.groovy**
The file should exist in src/main/resources.

see reference [spring boot logging docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)